# Recuperar uma avaliação geral e exibir em uma lista

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Boa noite pessoal, estou na seguinte situação,

Tenho uma tabela chamada carros, e cada carro pode ser avaliada por diferentes usuários, ate ai tudo bem, criei uma tabela secundaria chamada avaliações e cada carro pode ser avaliado por vários usuários diferentes.

Agora preciso que cada carro mostre uma avaliação geral, que e pegar todas as avaliações de todos os usuários em um determinado carro e mostrar em uma lista com todos os carros.

Ai que esta minha duvida, como recuperar todos as avaliações da tabela avaliação.

Inseri a Tabela para melhor entender, vou pegar so a somatória da avaliação geral e quantas pessoas avaliaram o mesmo carro exemplo

> GOLF - 2 Avaliações - 7 pontos

```
$sql = $conex->query("SELECT * FROM carros");
while($rs=$conex->result($sql)){
                    $id_car=$rs['id_car'];
                    $nome_car=$rs['nome_car'];
};
```

// Tabela ----------------------------------------------------------------

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `avaliacao` (
  `id_ava` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_car_ava` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_usu_ava` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dirigibilidade_ava` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `estabilidade_ava` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `potencia_ava` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `consumo_ava` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `geral_ava` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `avaliacao`
--

INSERT INTO `avaliacao` (`id_ava`, `id_car_ava`, `id_usu_ava`, `dirigibilidade_ava`, `estabilidade_ava`, `potencia_ava`, `consumo_ava`, `geral_ava`) VALUES
(1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4),
(2, 1, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5),
(3, 2, 7, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3),
(4, 3, 9, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `carros`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carros` (
  `id_car` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `model_car` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `ano_car` int(12) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `carros`
--

INSERT INTO `carros` (`id_car`, `model_car`, `ano_car`) VALUES
(1, 'Golf', 2000),
(2, 'Pálo', 1998),
(3, 'Jeta', 2015),
(4, 'Peugeout 206', 2006);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `avaliacao`
--
ALTER TABLE `avaliacao`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_ava`);

--
-- Indexes for table `carros`
--
ALTER TABLE `carros`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_car`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `avaliacao`
--
ALTER TABLE `avaliacao`
  MODIFY `id_ava` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `carros`
--
ALTER TABLE `carros`
  MODIFY `id_car` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Answer (score 1):

O SQL que pretende

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM avaliacao WHERE id_car_ava=id_car) AS QT FROM carros
```

Exemplo.:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23cfaf/2

Comment: Obrigado Thiago!

O lance e que e em outra tabela, não na mesma dos carros, entende, tenho que pegar todos as avaliações da outra tabela referente ao carro e mostrar na listagem geral dos carros.

Tenho a tabela, Avaliações e a tabela Carros

Comment: ok, na sua pergunta acrescente as tabelas de base dados por favor

Comment: Após acrescentar as tabelas eu editarei a minha resposta

Comment: Ok, Tiago Gomes, alterei la, e inseri mais detalhes, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Thiago Mais Uma vez obrigado, so mais uma questão, alem de exibir quantas pessoas votaram, eu teria que pegar a somatória dos votos, daria para fazer neste mesmo select?

Creio que seria isso!
Mais minha duvida e como exibir na leta.

`SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM avaliacao WHERE id_car_ava=id_car ),(SELECT SUM(geral_ava) FROM avaliacao WHERE id_car_ava = id_car ) AS QT FROM carros`

Comment: veja se é isso que pretende.: SELECT
 *,
 (
  SELECT
   COUNT(*)
  FROM
   avaliacao
  WHERE
   id_car_ava=id_car
 ) AS QT_AVALIACAO,
 (
  SELECT
   COALESCE(SUM(geral_ava),0)
  FROM
   avaliacao
  WHERE
   id_car_ava = id_car
 )  AS QT_PESSOAS
FROM
 carros